# Can a replication subscription also be used as a publication?

Tags: sql-server, replication

Some background:  We are working with a vendor who makes a read-only copy of their source database available to us in the cloud via filtered transactional replication.  The cloud database is a subscriber to the source database's publications.  The publishing database is multi-tenant, so only our customer data is replicated to our read-only copy.
The question is:  Could we could we publish from the subscriber/cloud database to a subscribing database in one of our own data centers?  If so, how might that work and would it be a management nightmare?

Answer (score 0):

> Could we could we publish from the subscriber/cloud database to a subscribing database in one of our own data centers?

Sure.  See [Republish Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/republish-data?view=sql-server-2017).  You would need to be the admins of the instance hosting the subscription database to make this all work.